How to solve the error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: dev/failsafe/Policy
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: dev/failsafe/Policy
    at org.seleniumhq.selenium.http/org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.ClientConfig.<clinit>(ClientConfig.java:33)
    at org.seleniumhq.selenium.chrome_driver/org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:83)
    at org.seleniumhq.selenium.chrome_driver/org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:51)
    at JavaIntroduction/SeleniumIntro.SampleCode.main(SampleCode.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: dev.failsafe.Policy
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
    ... 4 more

Run this below simple code,
package SeleniumIntro;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class SampleCode {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\MS Amlin\\driver\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
    }

}

Chrome version: 128.0.6613.120 (Official Build) (64-bit)
